# How To Load Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, document-body

So I have [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TsxzR/682/)

Which works how I want it to. But, the issue is I can not get it to work on my site. I have

```
$( ".total" ).change(function hello() { 
   140 Lines of code from fiddle
}
```

in between script tags in my body. 
I have

```
<script src="/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">< /script>
```

in my head. I have the jquery downloaded, its in my public_html (godaddy hosting with linux cpanel) and you can see it's on my [SITE](http://natecalvert.org/jquery-3.1.1.min.js) 
 My body tag looks like this

```
<body onload="hello()">
```

and my code was literally copied and pasted from the fiddle. With the First Lines of the table looking like this

```
<label id="printchatbox" ></label>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="number" class="total" name='barrelwrap' value "<?=isset($_POST['barrelwrap']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['barrelwrap']) : '' ?>">
   </td>
   <td>Barrel Wrap 47"x31" </td>
   <td id='barrelwrapPrice'>39.38 </td>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="number" class="total" name="smallcase" value "<?= isset($_POST['smallcase']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['smallcase']) : '' ?>">
   </td>
   <td>Case Card - Small 4.25"x11" </td>
   <td id='smallcasePrice'>1.50 </td>
  </tr>
```

The first lines of my script, again copies and pasted.

```
$( ".total" ).change(function hello() {
 var barrelwrapInput = document.getElementsByName('barrelwrap')[0];
 var smallcaseInput = document.getElementsByName('smallcase')[0];
 var mediumcaseInput = document.getElementsByName('mediumcase')[0];
 var largecaseInput = document.getElementsByName('largecase')[0];
 var coolerclingInput = document.getElementsByName('coolercling')[0];
 var poletopperInput = document.getElementsByName('poletopper')[0];
 var smallflyerInput = document.getElementsByName('smallflyer')[0];
 var largerflyerInput = document.getElementsByName('largerflyer')[0];
 var shelftagInput = document.getElementsByName('shelftag')[0];
 var stanchionInput = document.getElementsByName('stanchion')[0];
 var smallwindowInput = document.getElementsByName('smallwindow')[0];
```

Anyone have any idea what i've done wrong?

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log)

Comment: `<script src="/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">< /script>` the close tag needs to be `</script>` , without the space.

Comment: I have checked my console. There are errors, but all of them have to do with not being able to find OTHER references. i know no space, That was me pressing space one too many times

Comment: Looking at that fiddle, it is immediately apparent that there are problems as source code is being displayed in the output.

Comment: @Segmentation The space is an annoyance, but will have no bearing on the closing tag working properly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry, I'm working in a .php originally, just some php code left over, doesn't show on my page on the site.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i tried it out to be sure before posting. Even though it loaded the script the rest of the page did not load. Went back to check the code and all `html` code under the closing `script` tag was white (no syntax style was applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Even though the file is on your site, you may not be referencing it correctly. Different servers have different configurations and
>   requirements that may affect whether these reference rules work or
>   not.**

**For example, GoDaddy web hosting often provides an "httpDocs" folder at the root of a web site. You don't have to use it, but that's where their servers expect the site's content to be placed. Not following those rules result in relative paths not working.**

But, before we get further into this. Have you tried linking to JQuery from a hosted source, like:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If using this works, then the problem is definitely your reference to your local JQuery file. If that's the case, then read on...

If the resource you need is part of the same web site (not talking about folder structure here, talking about domain), you should use relative paths, where:

a. **fileName.ext** is all you need if the resource is in the same folder as the currently loaded document.

b. **folderName/fileName.ext** is what you need if the file you need is in a sub-folder of the current folder that the loaded document is in.

c. **../fileName.ext** is what to use if the file you need is one directory higher than the current document's folder. The ../ can be repeated if you need to go up more than one level (i.e. ../../fileName.ext).

d. **/fileNameext** or **/folderName/fileName.ext** indicates that the file or folder specified should be found starting from the root of the web site, regardless of where the current document is.
If the resource you need is located on another domain, you'd use an Absolute Path (http://something.something/file.ext).

e. **DO NOT use absolute paths for local resources!** This may work but causes the domain name to have to be resolved again, resulting in a longer load time.

**WARNING**:  Many servers are hosted on operating systems the have case-sensitive file systems, so always refer to files and folders in the same case that is actually used. Again, not doing this may work for you locally, while you develop (because you haven't moved the files to the remote server yet), but don't let that lull you into thinking that case doesn't matter.

Comment: I changed it, I tried changing the head <script> and the <script> in the body when calling it... neither worked.

Comment: If using the link to the hosted JQuery file didn't work, then you've got other issues. Have you looked in your console to see what errors are listed?

Comment: yes. 5 errors, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://natecalvert.org/resources/demos/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
request.php:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noWeekends' of undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ request.php:42fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617

Comment: and 
http://natecalvert.org/resources/demos/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://natecalvert.org/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So you need to address those issues first.

Comment: It's Working! it was   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> that was messing it up.... how?